# Zxing in portrait causes picture to be compressed and scanning to slow or fail

Tags: android, android-camera, qr-code, zxing, portrait

I've built a project based on the zxing 1.7 package, and done modifications according to posts in the issue #178 thread (that has vanished recently). The problem I'm facing is that the QR codes get compressed/squished, and this causes problems with the scanning.
I'm not looking for anyone to do my coding for me, but if someone knows of this issue or has an idea about what could be causing it, I would greatly appreciate it if you let me know.

Comment: Have you tried the latest 2.0 package? It even comes with core.jar already compiled :O

Comment: I have not tried the new package as of yet since we have integrated the 1.7 package (or rather parts of it) into our own project. Any suggestions on what could be the cause of the problems as described is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The tweak is simple, though need a little bit of changes across multiple files. Here I have put a complete solution for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252791/how-to-show-zxing-camera-in-portrait-mode-on-android/16252917#16252917

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Issue 178 was deleted because it was just getting spammed. I reopened it temporarily just for your reference: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=178)

Yes you should use 2.0, but it is not the problem. You are not configuring the camera properly to work in portrait orientation. You need to call `setDisplayOrientation()` as well as choose a preview size that (roughly) matches your screen aspect ratio. If you don't, you'll get the issues you see.

This is nothing to do with the library though, but your app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for opening the issue. I never said it was a problem with the library, I only asked for advice about what could be causing my problem.